# Is it possible call the trigger from file exported by Reality Composer?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

Is it possible call the trigger from reality file exported by Composer?

Due to I would like to upload reality file on cloud, and instantiate it into Entity.

However, I can't find the any code to trigger the notification such as:

```
entity.notifications.post()
```